# Error '1004' en tiempo de ejecucion: Error definido por la aplicacion o el objeto - Planilla de filtros mientras se escribe

Tags: vba

tengo el siguiente Codigo en una TextBox. El problema es que la segunda vez que abro el archivo me arroja esta ventana: Se ha producido el error '1004' en tiempo de ejecucion: Error definido por la aplicacion o el objeto. Y cuando hago correr la macro me marca esta linea.

Range("A5").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=Columna, Criteria1:=Criterio.

Como puedo eliminar el mensaje, he visto ya muchos tutoriales y no he podido resolverlo.

Adjunto Macros.

```
Private Sub Textbox1_Change()

    Dim Criterio As String
    Dim Columna As Integer

    If Hoja1.TextBox1.Value <> "" Then
        If Hoja1.ComboBox1.Value = "" Then Exit Sub
            If Hoja1.CheckBox1.Value = True Then
                Criterio = Hoja1.TextBox1.Value
            Else
                Criterio = "*" & Hoja1.TextBox1.Value & "*"
            End If
            Columna = Hoja1.ComboBox1.ListIndex + 1
            Range("A5").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=Columna, Criteria1:=Criterio
        Else
            Criterio = ""
            Range("A5").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Edité tu código para darle visibilidad y creo que te falta un cierre de un if. Revísalo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pon esto justo antes de tu primer If...

```
If Hoja1.AutoFilterMode Then
   Hoja1.AutoFilterMode = False
End If
```

Tu código corregido debería ser:

Private Sub Textbox1_Change()

```
Dim Criterio As String
Dim Columna As Integer

If Hoja1.AutoFilterMode Then
    Hoja1.AutoFilterMode = False
End If

If Hoja1.TextBox1.Value <> "" Then
    If Hoja1.ComboBox1.Value = "" Then Exit Sub
    
    If Hoja1.CheckBox1.Value = True Then
        Criterio = Hoja1.TextBox1.Value
    Else
        Criterio = "*" & Hoja1.TextBox1.Value & "*"
    End If
    Columna = Hoja1.ComboBox1.ListIndex + 1
    Hoja1.Range("$A$1:$D$999").AutoFilter Field:=Columna, Criteria1:=Criterio
Else
    Criterio = ""
    Hoja1.AutoFilterMode = False
End If
```

End Sub

Ojo, modifica el rango A1:D999 con lo que necesites abarcar.

Saludos.

Comment: Super, me funciono de maravilla. Gracias por tu ayuda :)

Comment: Me alegro de que te sirviera. Por favor, marca la respuesta cómo que es correcta.
Gracias.